# CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError in PhoneGap+Sencha+ Android Application

Tags: android, sencha-touch, cordova

When i load from the html file which is developed by sencha touch is generating error as follows :

> **`E/CordovaWebView(1897): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR! CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6
>   Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
>   URL=file:///android_asset/www/index.html`**

index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Creating a simple XTemplate list in Sencha Touch 2</title>
<link
    href="http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/resources/css/sencha-touch.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<script
    src="http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="app/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
/*global Ext:false */
Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            data: [{
                fname: 'Stratton',
                lname: 'Sclavos',
                role: 'Executive Chairman'
            }, {
                fname: 'Michael',
                lname: 'Mullany',
                role: 'CEO'
            }, {
                fname: 'Ted',
                lname: 'Driscoll',
                role: 'Vice President Worldwide Sales'
            }, {
                fname: 'Abraham',
                lname: 'Elias',
                role: 'Chief Technical Officer'
            }, {
                fname: 'Jeff',
                lname: 'Hartley',
                role: 'Vice President of Services and Training'
            }, {
                fname: 'Adam',
                lname: 'Mishcon',
                role: 'Vice President of Operations'
            }, {
                fname: 'Judy',
                lname: 'Lin',
                role: 'Vice President of Engineering'
            }], // data
            tpl: '<tpl for="."><div><strong>{lname}</strong>, {fname} <em class="muted">({role})</em></div></tpl>'
        }); // create()
    } // launch
}); // application()
```

MainActivity,java

```
package com.example.senchahelloandroid;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can do a few things to fix this:

- Check you have set the permission for INTERNET_CONNECTION in your
  AndroidManifest file.
- You might try downloading the linked files (**Sencha-touch.css** and **sencha-touch-all-debug.js**) from the internet and make them local.
- You can add this line **super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 7000);** under super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in your MainActivity.java file

Comment: i have made the above changes, then the apk can't install . Failed to install SenchaHelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5556': timeout. Launch canceled!

Comment: Did you try increasing the timer value?? Like instead of 7000, you can put 10000 or more something like that

Comment: Did you try downloading the linked files from Sencha repository?? I guess you used Sencha Architect to create Sencha files. Maybe, localizing those files could help? Just give it a try..

Comment: i have made changes mentioned on above answer